# Best relational database structure for this data

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I'm in the process of creating a database scheme for the following scenario:

- There are users
- Users have roles (such as "Developer" or "CEO")
- Roles have applications (such as "Topdesk")
- Applications have permissions (such as "Update Knowledgebase")
- A role can have permissions, if the role already has access to the application

Assuming no high-performance environment (no need to optimize for speed), what would be the best way to implement this schema? The database environment can be MySQL, MSSQL... it's more about the relational database design.

I myself have come up with the following:

[image: ERD Diagram]

The part I'm most uncertain about is of course the Applications_Permissions_Roles table. It is a linking table *on top of* another linking table. I've never used or seen this before. Another way to do it would be to replace it with a linking table between Roles and Permissions, and then use code or constrains to ensure the required relations... but that doesn't seem like a good solution to me. These things should be enforced on database-level if at all possible (and it seems possible), not on code-level.

Secondly, is the link between Permissions.Application and Applications.Id required? I use it because there may not be any rows in Roles_Applications (such as when you've just added a new application) and then it's not possible to work out which permissions belong to which application. It also is a single point of reference to lookup to which application a permission belongs. I guess this is right, but it also makes a circle in the database design. MSSQL errors on it when trying to set ON_DELETE or ON_UPDATE to cascade.

Any suggestions, or is this how it's supposed to be done? Any other suggestions regarding naming convention and such are also welcome by the way (perhaps as comment).

Thanks,
Luc

*Edit:* Changed title, hopefully making it clearer. The previous one was more comprehensive, but probably too convoluted.

Comment: I'm not sure I've wrapped my mind around the interplay of roles, applications, and permissions.  Each role/application has a specific permission that is independent of a role's other applications?  For example, a CEO/Topdesk might have only read permission, while a CEO/Calendar might have write?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "best relational database schema for this data" do you mean what engine? Like Postgres or MySQL or MSSQL or ... etc?

Comment: @jcolebrand Guess the title is even less clear than before... Perhaps "database structure" is a better word. The table layout and relations (foreign keys, etc.).

Comment: @mdoyle Permissions are always within an application (example: permission 'change the system clock' in application 'windows') and thus a permission belongs to exactly one application. A role can have both permissions and applications, the only constraint being that if you have any permissions, you must also have access to the application to which the permissions belong. (Obviously if you can't use Topdesk, you can't have permission 'Update knowledgebase' for application Topdesk.) Does this make it clearer?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `Roles_Applications` is a real thing.  Given that all permissions are application-specific, it seems there are `Applications_Permissions` (what you have labeled `Permissions`), which may then be assigned to specific roles via a record in `Applications_Permissions_Roles`.  `Roles_Applications`, in fact, seems to be describing the most basic application permission--simple access.  Or, it is asserting that a role has *some* level of permissions for an application, but you have to look elsewhere to determine which ones.

Comment: @mdoyle Hmm I'm not sure I follow you. Isn't what you are suggesting the same as Joel Brown's second suggestion? If not, perhaps write this up as an answer. Your comment already sounds much like an answer, and an answer also gives some more space to explain. In any case, thanks for your response!

Comment: Sure, give me a minute or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've modelled it is fine.  Your model ensures that the business rules are enforced by the database.

There are a couple of things you could do as an alternative.  One would be to eliminate the surrogate key on `Roles_Applications`.  As an intersection table, you could use the two foreign keys together as a composite primary key.  If you did this, that would propagate `Role` and `Application` down to your `Applications_Permissions_Roles` table.  This would have the advantage of giving you more of a "one stop shop" for your application permission data (i.e. fewer joins) without compromising your normalization in any way.

Another way you could go would be to simplify slightly and define a default permission for each application.  You could call it whatever you like, such as "default access" or "basic access" or "user" or whatever makes sense to you.  This would allow you to flatten your model and essentially drop the `Roles_Applications` table and join `Applications_Permissions_Roles` straight to `Roles`.  This would change the nature of the query that you would use to ask "which roles can access which applications?" but your business rules would still be enforced by the schema.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I hadn't thought of these suggestions yet. The second suggestion would add a lot of application logic though: all places that handle permissions should check if an operation is not performed on the default permission (since that should not be mutable or perhaps even shown); and stuff dealing with applications should make sure the default permission is created or removed appropriately. It would simplify the database, but at a higher cost it seems. The first suggestion is an option though, I think I'll implement this. Thanks again for the review :)

Answer (score 1):

`Roles_Application` does not appear to represent a real thing here.  What is it, beyond signifying that a particular role has *some* level of permissions to an application, even though you need to check out `Applications_Permissions_Roles` to determine what that level is?   As an example, here is a CEO getting write access to the application Calendar in your current model:

**Roles**

```
ID    Name
--    ----
1     CEO
```

**Applications**

```
ID    Name
--    ----
C     Calendar
```

**Permissions**

```
ID    Application_ID  Permission
--    --------------  ----------
10    C               Write
```

**Roles_Applications**

```
ID    Role_ID    Application_ID
--    -------    --------------
50    1          C
```

**Applications_Permissions_Roles**

```
Role_Application_ID    Permission_ID
-------------------    -------------
50                     10
```

I think this series of relationships can be modeled without the `Roles_Applications`.  If we remove that (as Joel Brown suggests, but without the change of assuming there are "default permissions"):

**Roles**

```
ID    Name
--    ----
1     CEO
```

**Applications**

```
ID    Name
--    ----
C     Calendar
```

**Applications_Permissions** (nee `Permissions`)

```
ID    Application_ID  Permission
--    --------------  ----------
10    C               Write
```

**Applications_Permissions_Roles**

```
Role_ID    Application_Permission_ID
-------    -------------
1          10
```

The old `Permissions` table doesn't have simply permissions, like "read" and "write", which can then be applied to applications like "Topdesk" and "Calendar":  It contains application-specific permissions, like "write in Topdesk" and "write in Calendar" and "Change system clock in Windows".  To make that clearer I've named the table `Applications_Permissions` but of course that's not a necessary step.

This approach has the effect of flattening the model, as does Joel's second suggestion, but without adding application logic or the concept of default permissions.  `Roles_Applications` wasn't bringing anything to the party other than an indication that a role has some level of access to an application.  That information is conveyed with more brevity by the existence of a record in `Applications_Permissions_Roles` with the proper value of Role_ID.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. The issue is that one does not always have permissions on an application. Like with Microsoft Word, there simply are none. In those cases it's unknown which role can access which application; you must always have at least one permission from that application assigned to a role. That's what the "default permission" suggestion from Joel Brown was for. Thanks for the suggestion though! It's not a bad idea and makes sense, but I simply can't apply it to my situation. \*Upvoted*

Comment: For something like Word, isn't "execute" a permission?  But I see your point if for some reason executing or accessing an application isn't considered a permission.